# GIMP Stroke selection is disabled?

Tags: gimp, gif

I am working to make a border for a GIF. May I ask please how to enable the stroke selection for a new layer in GIMP?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from your screen shot, you haven't made a selection. *Stroke selection* will be greyed out if you don't have a selection.

The yellowish dotted line around your image is not a selection, it's only the layer boundary.

A selection looks different from the layer boundary, it has a "marching ants" animated effect, and is not yellowish.

You can switch off the layer boundary if it's confusing you. Click *View* in the main menu, and deselect the *Show Layer Boundary* option.

If you want to select the entire image hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>(Select all). Now you can stroke it using *Stroke Selection*.

Comment: thank you for your help. It is GIF file May I ask please if it is also true for GIF file?  I would like to add a border in a GIF file.

Comment: If you want to add a border to an animated GIF, then you'd have to add it on every frame of the animation, which could be a bit tedious. I'm unfamiliar with the GIMP FAnim Timeline plugin you are using, but if it's anything like Photoshop's timeline, then you could just add the border to a new transparent layer, and use the timeline plugin to add it to each frame (this is just a guess, so don't hold me to it).

Answer (score 1):

you can take you selection and left click it in the layer tab, select 'alpha to selection, then in the path tool, add a new path layer, and at the bottom use the 'selection to path' icon.  Then stroke path.